# Average on a field of collection with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

Suppose we have 2 entities:

```
 ----------------------            -------------
|                      | 1      * |             |
|        Teacher       |----------|   Student   |
|                      |          |             |
|----------------------|          |-------------|
|String name           |          |  Float mark |
|List<Student> students|           -------------
 ----------------------
```

So, Teacher has a list of students and student has a mark. Now how can I calculate the average marks for a teacher efficiently with Criteria API.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Object1, is the list supposed to be a list of Object2? If so, check this question out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2791378/does-the-jpql-avg-aggregate-function-work-with-integers) for JPQL. It looks like there is an AVG function.

Comment: Sorry I think the question was little bit ambiguous, I made it more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Projection to take care of this. Sample exaple will be...

```
session.createCriteria(//Your class)
.setProjection(Projections.avg("//property"))
```

Comment: Sorry I think the question was little bit ambiguous, The property itself is not single type, it's an object. I made my question more clear now, can you please check it again.